# floppy drive try to read directory and fail

Tags: interface, protocol

Equipment: NFA HP/Agilent/Keysight **N8973A**
With 3.5 floppy disk drive
I replaced by an emulator and the result is "**bad or missing disk**" after a trying to read the directory.
Reinstalling the original floppy drive, which was working, I got same result.
Seems that the equipment has a protection to avoid any unauthorized attempt to upgrade it or the FDC is now defective.
**Does someone have and can share the floppy drive communication protocol?**

Comment: Ok, thanks for this information. Sadly, StackExchange is not a diary.

Comment: I'm trying to get some help for my trouble.

Comment: Then ask a question, one that can be _answered_ and is _on-topic_.

Comment: Those aware enough to realize that the device in question is a **rather pricey piece of RF test equipment** might have a little more sympathy for the asker - arguably this is an EE tools question, not simply a repair one.  In fact this is a common problem, - such older but still valuable test gear is a big part of why such disk emulators exist.  It might be worth checking the cable connections.

Comment: Thanks Chris, you are polite and I recognize my lack of experience in this forum. Here is my question: does someone have and can share the floppy drive communication protocol?

Comment: Of course there are numerous people that have the floppy drive communication protocol. Obviously this includes various engineers that designed floppy controllers, or that had to write the firmware to interface with them. It should again be obvious that most of these people can share the protocol. Whether they wish to bother is a separate question. I once designed a floppy drive emulator. It had a PIC 16F877, back when that was the biggest bestes PIC around. I am therefore one of those that have the floppy protocol - somewhere. Whether I'm willing to share it is less certain since it means some

Comment: Is it a "normal" 1.44 MB MSDOS type drive or one of them obscure which used non-standard sector and track alignment to get higher capacity?

Comment: Some questions: is this floopy required for your hardware to work? Does it boot without it? Some equipment can't be used without the master disk, but others use it only to save data.

About protocols, I would try retrocomputing groups. Some guys on there are masters on abandoned tech and protocols. I once helped a guy on getting the image of his protocol analyzer and "burning" it back to a real floppy disk, and it worked. It was a non-standard disk (not readable by a PC) but I have found a DOS utility that could command the floopy drive directly to do non-standard things.

Comment: So it had a perfectly good 1.44mb floppy drive, which you replaced with an emulator - and now it's broken? Oops!

Comment: I would have thought this is better suited to superuser SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the NFA firmware upgrade from [Keysight Technologies,](http://www.keysight.com/main/software.jspx?cc=ID&lc=eng&nid=-11143.0.00&id=1000000894:epsg:sud&pageMode=CV) and created the loader disk. I then analyzed the disk with the DOS program 'Anadisk' which is able to read many different formats. Here are a couple of screenshots:-

[image]

[image]

It appears to be standard PC 1.44MB format, which suggests that the N8973A disk drive is also a standard 1.44MB mechanism and its 'communication protocol' is probably the same as a normal PC.

The IBM PC floppy drive interface is well documented, so the information you need shouldn't be too hard to find. Here's something to get you started:-

[IBM PS/2 3.5 inch Diskette Drives Technical Reference](http://www.mcamafia.de/pdf/ps2_fdd_trm_s42g2194_00.pdf)

[Diskette Drive Controller](http://www.mcamafia.de/pdf/ibm_hitrc06.pdf)